# Add Keys to array

Tags: php, arrays, dom

```
array { [0]=>
 City
 Street
 Zip
```

I have this but what I need is something like:

```
array { [0]=> 
 'city'=>City
 'Street'=>Street
 'zip'=>Zip
```

I am using PHPDOM to get the html which I than add to an array

```
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element) {
    if (strpos($element->getAttribute('class'), 'contentSection') !== false) {
        $string = $element->C14N();
    }
}

$array = explode("</p>", $string);
print_r($array);
```

HTML part that I am processing with DOM

```
 <div class="contentSection">

    City
    <br>
    Street
    <br>
    ZIP                

    <p class="Separator">
    </p>

    City
    <br>
    Street
    <br>
    ZIP
```

Something that I tried to do is

```
  $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element) {
        if (strpos($element->getAttribute('class'), 'contentSection') !== false) {
            $string = $element->C14N();
        }
    }

        $keys = array("city","street", "zip");
$array = array_explode_with_keys("<br>", $keys, $string);
        print_r($array);

    function array_explode_with_keys($delimiter, $keys, $string){
        $return = array();
        $pieces = explode($delimiter,$string);
        foreach($pieces as $i=>$piece){
            if($i<count($keys)) {
                $return[$keys[$i]] = $piece;
            } else {
                $return[$i] = $piece;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

    ?>
```

but this returns:

```
Array ( [city] =>
city[street] =>
street [zip] =>
zip

city [3] =>
street [4] =>
zip
```

So it goes wrong in the second part

Comment: Can you show us html part please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this 
You need to recreate an associative array.

```
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element) {
    if (strpos($element->getAttribute('class'), 'contentSection') !== false) {
        $string = $element->C14N();
    }
}

$array = explode("</p>", $string);
foreach($array as $arr){
    $array[$arr] = $arr; //Adding Keys to array same as value of array
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach($array as $value){
   $data[$value] = $value;
}
print_r($data);
```

May be solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element) {
    if (strpos($element->getAttribute('class'), 'contentSection') !== false) {
        $string = $element->C14N();
    }
}
$array = explode('<br>',explode("</p>", $string));
foreach($array as $arr){
    $v = trim(strip_tags($arr)); //remove html tags
    $out[$v] = $v; 
}
print_r($out);
```