# Give names to array keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

So I have this code:

```
<?php
$csv = array();
$lines = file('file.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $csv[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

which gives me the following

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => value3
            [3] => value4
```

How can I name my keys? so I don't see 0-1-2-3 but Name1-Name2-Name3 etc.

Like This:

```
  [0] => Array
        (
            [Name0] => value1
            [Name1] => value2
            [Name2] => value3
            [Name3] => value4
```

Comment: You can accomplish it by a simple `for` loop and a new array. Research a little more.

Comment: any relation to your other question by any chance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626445/add-keys-to-array

Comment: People need to learn how to learn.

Comment: @AlanMachado I once was taught how to fish. Now I have a fleet of trollers doing the job for me.

Comment: Please give a proper example of what you want the array to look like, preferably one that matches some example input so the transition **is obvious**

Comment: `$keys = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'etc']; $csv[$key] = array_combine($keys, str_getcsv($value));`

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker Baker that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function csvToArray($filename, $delimiter = ',') {
        if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $header = NULL;
        $data = array();

        if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
                if (count($row) > 0 && !is_null($row[0])) {
                    if (!$header) {
                        $header = $row;
                    } else {
                        $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

Try this function
$filename is the full path to the file
also add in csv as first line keys you want to have and function will use this first line for keys

csv example:

"id","country","city"

"1","us","abanda"

"2","us","abbeville"

Comment: You are supposed to answer the question, not just paste some code you have lying around into an answer.

Comment: I'm having a deja vu http://www.saviost.net/php-convert-csv-to-array/ (yet, another ***try this***)

Comment: RiggsFolly this is the answer i not see you to give us better answer!
 Alan Machado do you except me to discover ameriga again ?

Comment: @AlanMachado I wonder if [this...](http://trythis.com/) is where they're all signing up?

Comment: @Fred-ii- please tell me you just deployed it for the sake of the joke.

Comment: @AlanMachado You're *sharp as a tack* ;-)

Comment: @SkyFox being able to point an error does **not** oblige one to provide solutions, even thou it's expected. Being hurt by being proved wrong make people believe that. Nevertheless the point is, if the answer can be googled, then the question shouldn't exist, and the answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand!

All you need to do in this case is concatenate a string literal onto the front of the key that you generate, like this :-

```
<?php
$csv = array();
$lines = file('file.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $csv['Name'.$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: and Smokey clears the air. Ooops... green tick disappeared. *Poof!* Just like magic huh Smokey?

Comment: Think it's actually the keys of the sub-array, not the top-level

Comment: @RiggsFolly I hear you. I removed my comment because it was based on the OP's original question which made it seem like he wanted to start at `Name1` but is now showing `Name0`. Anywho, on to the next Q.

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'etc']; 
$csv[$key] = array_combine($keys, str_getcsv($value));
```

This worked

Thanks Mark Baker